# Rational class supporting precise numbers

Tags: javascript, rational-numbers

This is my JavaScript `Rational` class, similar to other languages' `BigFraction` class, but with one major difference:

This class doesn't support arbitrarily large rational numbers:

i.e. `new Rational(Number.MAX_VALUE + 1)` may fail.
However, it supports arbitrarily precise numbers
i.e. `new Rational(1, 10).add(new Rational(2, 10))` will be *exactly* `new Rational(3, 10)` instead of `.3000000000004`.

```
window.Rational = (function() {
  var GCF, LCM;

  // Internal GCF and LCM

  GCF = function(a, b) {
    var temp;
    if (a < 0) a *= -1;
    if (b < 0) b *= -1;
    if (a < b) {
      temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp;
    }
    return a % b === 0 ? b : GCF(a % b, b);
  };

  LCM = function(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a * b) / GCF(a, b);
  };

  function Rational(top, bottom) {
    this.top = top;
    // bottom defaults to 1
    this.bottom = bottom != null ? bottom : 1;
    this.simplify();
  }

  Rational.prototype.add = function(other) {
    var lcm = LCM(this.bottom, other.bottom);
    // If we multiply by lcm
    // it becomes an integer
    // but we round to prevent floating point innacuracies
    var top1 = Math.round(this * lcm);
    var top2 = Math.round(other * lcm);
    return new Rational(top1 + top2, lcm);
  };

  Rational.prototype.subtract = function(other) {
    return this.add(other.multiply(Rational.constants.NEGATIVE_ONE));
  };

  Rational.prototype.multiply = function(other) {
    return new Rational(this.top * other.top, this.bottom * other.bottom);
  };

  Rational.prototype.divide = function(other) {
    return this.multiply(other.reciprocal());
  };

  Rational.prototype.reciprocal = function() {
    return new Rational(this.bottom, this.top);
  };

  Rational.prototype.isLessThan = function(other) {
    return this < other;
  };

  Rational.prototype.isGreaterThan = function(other) {
    return this > other;
  };

  Rational.prototype.isEqualTo = function(other) {
    return this.top === other.top && this.bottom === other.bottom;
  };

  Rational.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.top / this.bottom;
  };

  Rational.prototype.simplify = function() {
    var gcf;
    if (this.top === 0) {
      // No need to calculate GCF because GCF = 0
      this.bottom = 1;
      return;
    }
    if (this.bottom === 0) {
      throw new Error("Cannot have denominator 0");
    }
    gcf = GCF(this.top, this.bottom);
    if (this.top < 0 && this.bottom < 0) {
      // Since GCF doesn't handle negatives
      // if both numerator and denominators are negative
      // we can cancel the negative
      gcf *= -1;
    }
    // If the bottom is less than zero, then move the negative sign to the top
    if (this.bottom < 0 && this.top >= 0) {
      this.top *= -1;
      this.bottom *= -1;
    }
    this.top /= gcf;
    this.bottom /= gcf;
    return this;
  };


  Rational.constants = {
    ZERO: new Rational(0),
    ONE: new Rational(1),
    NEGATIVE_ONE: new Rational(-1)
  };
  return Rational;

})();
```

Questions:

- I think that by doing `this * 5` or `other * 6`, I implicitly call `valueOf()`. Is that okay? Should I make it explicit (to me, saying `this * 5` is clear: multiply `this` by 5), but I'm not sure in general.
- Same as the question above for `this < other` and `this > other`.
- Can I refactor my `GCF` and `LCM` algorithms to take into account negative numbers so that I don't have to handle them as special cases in the `simplify` function? Right now, they simply make everything positive and return a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I noticed some bugs:

```
LCM = function(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a * b) / GCF(a, b);
};
```

The computation of `a * b` will easily overflow (thus losing precision) for large numbers `a`, `b`. You can improve matters by rewriting it as

```
function LCM(a, b) {
  var g = a / GCF(a,b);
  return Math.abs(g * b);
}
```

I also used `function LCM` as opposed to `LCM = function` just as a stylistic preference. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/1424877)

Similarly:

```
Rational.prototype.add = function(other) {
  var lcm = LCM(this.bottom, other.bottom);
  // If we multiply by lcm
  // it becomes an integer
  // but we round to prevent floating point innacuracies
  var top1 = Math.round(this * lcm);
  var top2 = Math.round(other * lcm);
  return new Rational(top1 + top2, lcm);
};
```

If I understand correctly, in the expression `this * lcm`, `lcm` is a Number, so you're basically doing `this.valueOf() * lcm`, which again wipes out all your pretended precision. You should avoid big numbers (which become floating-point), and you should *definitely* avoid unnecessary floating-point divisions.

```
Rational.prototype.add = function(other) {
  var lcm = LCM(this.bottom, other.bottom);
  var top1 = this.top * (lcm / this.bottom);
  var top2 = other.top * (lcm / other.bottom);

  return new Rational(top1 + top2, lcm);
};
```

Comment: Your add function doesn't work. It should be `lcm / this.bottom` not `this.bottom / lcm`. But isn't that the same thing: `this.top * (lcm / this.bottom)` and `(this.top / this.bottom) * lcm`?

Comment: Good catch; I'll fix it inline. But to your question: No! A concrete example is top=3, bottom=47, lcm=188. `(3 * (188/47))` is correctly `12`, but `(3/47) * 188` is incorrectly `11.999999999999998`. Try it for yourself! :)  Remember, the **whole point** of your project is to use exact rational representations, so **any** time you have to drop into floating-point should be a huge red flag to you.